# PHP and JS / jQuery array setup

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I'm stuck with this. I'm creating user access control by module ADD,EDIT,DELETE,VIEW .I want these tree arrays with equal count even if its null. I'm using checkbox for command access and insert to database by row

Given Code:

```
<?php
$select = $mysqli->query("SELECT SubMenuCode FROM tblsubmenuaccess WHERE EmployeeID='24'")or die($mysqli->error);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($select);
if ($numrows>0):

echo '  
<table>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
';
while($row= $select->fetch_object())
{
echo '  
<tr>

<td><input type="text" class="submenu" name="submenu[]" value="'.$row->SubMenuCode.'"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="cmdAdd" name="cmdAdd[]" value="ADD" >ADD </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="cmdEdit" name="cmdEdit[]" value="EDIT" >EDIT </td>
</tr>       
';
}                           
echo '
<input type="submit" id="btn-save" name="submit" value="save"> 
</form>
</table>
';                      
endif;



// I want this output:
//submenu         //cmdAdd      //cmdEdit
//Accounts          ADD           EDIT
//Trialbalance      null          EDIT
//Productlist       ADD           EDIT
//Atd               ADD           null

?>
```

hopefully there's someone who can help, thanks in advance!

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: the checkbox value always true or display the value even if its unchecked - (3) [Array(11), Array(11), Array(11)]
0
:
(11) ["accounts", "AdministratorUtilities", "Users", "UserSubModule", "Atd", "EmployeeInformation", "Payroll", "PayrollHeader", "AdjustmentIn", "Unittagging", "ProductList"]
1
:
(11) ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
2
:
(11) ["EDIT", "EDIT", "EDIT", "EDIT", "EDIT", "EDIT", "EDIT", "EDIT", "EDIT", "EDIT", "EDIT"]
length
:
3

Comment: $( "#sform" ).submit(function( event ) {
  
   var _submenu = [];
   var _add = [];
   var _edit = [];

   $('.submenu').each(function(){
    _submenu.push($(this).val());
   });

   $('.cmdAdd').each(function(){
    
     if($(".cmdAdd").is("checked"))
     {
      $(this).val("ADD");
     }
     else
     {
      $(this).val(null);
     }

     
    //$(this).prop(":checked") ? $(this).val() : null;
    console.log($(this).val());
    _add.push($(this).val());
   });

Comment: @jayson : Have you've solve your concern yet?

Comment: not yet sir until now but i'm continuing searching to solve this and waiting to someone who can help. Thank you